# Create a regular expression to extract the first part of the $request variable for use in the nginx log format

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm using NginX on a Raspberry Pi (Buster).  I would like to extract the two items from the $request variable:

> /folder/asp/DataWrite2File.asp?time=2022-04-10+01%3A04&temp1=20.0&temp2=19.687&temp3=19.75&temp4=19.625
> HTTP/1.1

Basically I want to use a regular expression to a) capture everything before the "?" and b) the "Http/1.1" part for use in my NginX server block log format directive.

And, if there is no "?" then I want the whole $request variable.

I'm new to the use of regular expressions and so far Googling has only confused me more. Can someone help?....RDK

Comment: Or you could use `$uri` and `$server_protocol` which appear to be the two parts of the `$request` string that you are attempting to extract.

Comment: Works perfectly, but, aw shucks, I did  not learn anything about "regular expressions"

Comment: I can't post this as the "answer" since, while it works, it does not address my question on how it could be done with "regular expressions"..'